# Twilio - Recording + Transcribing While Sending DTMF Tones

Tags: twilio

I understand that if you initiate an outbound call using Java, you can do setRecord(true) to record the call. Is there a way to trigger transcription at the same time without using TwiML?

I understand that the TwiML contained at the URI you provide can contain a  verb which has the transcribe=true attribute, but my problem is that I can't do any other actions until the recording ends, and the url provided as the action parameter of the  verb gets hit.

I'd like to record and transcribe the entirety of the outbound call while sending DTMF tones during this call. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [record a call using the REST API parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) you do not have the option to transcribe the call from the API using the Twilio transcription service.

In fact, the Twilio transcription service can only be used when using the [`<Record>` TwiML and can only transcribe messages up to 2 minutes long](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe).

However there are [add-ons available from the Twilio marketplace](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133027-Transcribe-entire-phone-calls-with-Twilio) that you can use. You can use the [IBM Watson Speech to Text add-on](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons/ibm-watson-speechtotext) or [VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription](https://www.twilio.com/marketplace/add-ons/voicebase-transcription) add-on to transcribe calls that are initiated by the REST API. Both add-ons can also transcribe calls that are up to 4 hours long.

Let me know if this helps at all.